# Do I need return flight proof in order to board from Madrid to Montevideo with Iberia?

Tags: spain, iberia, uruguay, return, return-tickets

I'm French and am gonna travel soon from Madrid, Spain to Montevideo, Uruguay with the Spanish air company Iberia. I know that some companies require from their costumers to show a proof of the return flight to board (usually a return ticket). Does Iberia do that ? I browsed through their Website but could not find anything about it.

Comment: Whether the airline asks for a return ticket depends more on the traveler and the itinerary than the airline. Some countries require some visitors to have a return or onward ticket, and airlines have no choice but to enforce this.

Comment: I'm French and I'm going to stay less than 3 months, so I won't have visa.

Answer (score 4):

Timatic, the system used by airlines, does not mention an onward/return ticket as a requirement to enter Uruguay https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/oV86E3KXwm4lOgxIrBb7gW3B2UAa